# Mysql group by day

Tags: mysql

This is my tables :

```
car_event 
  id
  start_date

employee_car_event 
  car_event_id
  employee_id
```

Some employees works two time on one day.

In my exemple employee 1 and 2 work the same day two time.

I want to know how many days works each employees

I try to do :

```
select 

   count(employee_car_event.id) as nbrJour, 
   employee_car_event.employee_id as idEmployee,    
   DATE_FORMAT(car_event.startDate, '%Y%m%d') as gday

 from employee_car_event 
    left join 
    car_event on car_event.id = employee_car_event.car_event_id 
    group by gday, employee_car_event.employee_id
```

But i have this :

```
2 | 1 | 20170320
2 | 2 | 20170320
```

And i want :

```
1 | 1 | 20170320
1 | 2 | 20170320
```

Thank's a lot for your help

Comment: If you are having date too in selection, then count will always be 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this query

```
select 

   count(distinct employee_car_event.employee_id) as nbrJour, 
   employee_car_event.employee_id as idEmployee,    
   DATE_FORMAT(car_event.startDate, '%Y%m%d') as gday

 from employee_car_event 
    left join 
    car_event on car_event.id = employee_car_event.car_event_id 
    group by gday, employee_car_event.employee_id
```

Comment: To add an explanation, the key here is the "group by" clause at the end.  Essentially, it is grouping the output by day so if an employee works more than once per day, those records are collapsed into a single event.  It does mean that the output is only good for figuring out what days an employee worked and not whether it was the morning, night shift, or both.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.